# How do you style Wordpress sub-menus with CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to style my wordpress sub-menu with CSS to show only when a user hovers the "Color" menu item but I haven't succeed so I need some help please.

Here's how my menu looks like at this state:

[image]

The sub-menu shows all the time and there is a weird space after the "Color" menu item. Also, the sub-menu items are displayed one after another and not one below other like a drop-down menu should be.

Could you please help me out?

I'm aware that there are some similar questions to this one but they were of no help.

EDIT: added current CSS menu code that I have in my style.css

```
nav.main { float: left; }
nav.main li { float: left; margin-right: 11px; }
nav.main li.last-child { margin-right: 0; }
nav.main li a {
color: #7A0018;
display: block;
font-size: 13px;
padding: 50px 7px 22px 7px;
text-decoration: none;
}
nav.main li a:hover { background: #fbf6dc;  }
nav.main li.current-menu-item a { background: #fbf6dc; }
```

Comment: can you please provide your code so that we can troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: @TheNewbie I've added the CSS code that I've currently got in my style.css for menus.

Comment: i would highly suggest to play around with the Web Developer tools in either Chrome or Firefox when it comes to CSS with Wordpress.  Each theme is unique and handles CSS differently so it is hard for us to give you accurate answers.  Just open the Elements section of the Web Dev tools and you can add/change/modify any CSS rules that you would like and the page will update automatically.  Once you get the page styled how you would like you can then just copy and paste your temporary rules into styles.css or wherever your theme puts custom styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where is css for your child list items ? you haven't use **display property** for those **sub-menu** which should be done **none** first then only on hovering them you have to change display property **'block'**.

You have given margin-right property 11px; where as **ul** on default also occupies some margin.

Can you also provide your html frame (code)?